# Table numbering in while loop

Tags: php, pagination

I have pagination page using php. And I add the `$i` in my table  to have numbering in my table. I set the records per page into 10. The problem is, when I click the next or the page 2 the number in my while loop is back in 1-10. How I can continue the numbering of my table?

I have 166 records. Records should display 1-10 page 1 and 11-20 page 2 and so on.

```
<?php
  echo'<table>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
         </tr> ';
  $i = 1;
  while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo'<tr>
           <td>'.$i++.'</td>
         </tr>';
  }
  echo'</table>';
?>
```

this is some details of my pagination

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
$id2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
if (isset($_GET['id'])) { 
    $id2 = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
} else { 
    $id2 = 1;
} 
$itemsPerPage = 10; 
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
if ($id2 < 1) { 
    $id2 = 1; 
} else if ($id2 > $lastPage) { 
    $id2 = $lastPage; 
}
```

Comment: please provide full code for pagination .You have provided incomplete code.how you are setting page variable and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add page number, Replace your `$_GET['page']` with your approprite. Assumed `yourpage.php?page=2`

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $i = (($_GET['page']-1) * 10)+1; // You current page number x No.of records + 1 // 2page * 10 reocrds per page + 1 = 21;
}else{
  $i = 1;
}
```

Comment: What is ur query string parametername

Comment: why when I click the next page it's starts at 21?

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

Chang `$i` value with page number.

```
$i = $page_no * $page_size + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `$i = 1;` before `while` and place it inside the loop

```
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
{
  echo'<tr>
  <td>'.$i++.'</td> /* increment i here will be hust fine */
  </tr>';
}
```

This way, every time when your loop runs, `i` would be iterated to call exactly the count its supposed to!!

Comment: the results is starting at blank to 1-9

Answer (score 0):

You can simply multiply page number and page size and add your current number

```
$totalpagerows = 10;    
    if($_GET['page']!=""){
      if($_GET['page']>1){
         $pagenew =$_GET['page']-1;
      }
      else{
          pagenew =1;
      }

        $i = ($pagenew  * $totalpagerows )+1;     
    }else{
      $i = 1;
    }
```

Comment: why when I click the next page it's starts at 21?